# Pré selecionar ultimo registro em um DropDownList c#

Tags: c#, dropdown, webforms

Estou atribuindo uma lista para o `DataSource`, e nessa atribuição estou concatenando o código com o nome da empresa, porém, ele carrega a lista com o primeiro item selecionado.
Como faço para que o ultimo registro carregue pré-selecionado ?

Meu código está assim:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < empresa.Count; i++)
    {
            empresa[i].ParEmpresa = empresa[i].ParCodigo + " - " + empresa[i].ParEmpresa;
    }
    ddlEmpIni.DataSource = empresa;
    ddlEmpIni.DataTextField = "ParEmpresa";
    ddlEmpIni.DataValueField = "ParCodigo";
    ddlEmpIni.DataBind();
```

Comment: Já Tentou? `ddlEmpIni.SelectedValue = ddlEmpIni.items[ddlEmpIni.items.count].ParCodigo`

Comment: Obrigado @Marconi já consegui com o empresa[i],ParCodigo dentro do laço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim

```
    for (int i = 0; i < empresa.Count; i++)
    {
            empresa[i].ParEmpresa = empresa[i].ParCodigo + " - " + empresa[i].ParEmpresa;
    }
    ddlEmpIni.DataSource = empresa;
    ddlEmpIni.DataTextField = "ParEmpresa";
    ddlEmpIni.DataValueField = "ParCodigo";
    ddlEmpIni.DataBind();
    ddlEmpIni.SelectedValue = empresa[empresa.Count()].ParCodigo;
```

Comment: não tem a propriedade "length" brother.

Comment: Use o Count(), de qualquer modo, pega o último elemento, pode até usar o i

Comment: Não funcionou @PauloHDSousa

Comment: usa o I então... aquele que voce usou no i++, caso nao funcione usa i - 1